# React TS function argument types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

There is a HOC component for storing the value of one state for all elements as input, select. The output function accepts an arguments  `({text: Component, select: Component})`. While typing an argument, an error is displayed as

```
TS2322: Type '({ settings }: Param) => (type: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'FC<Param>'.   Type '(type: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key
```

**app.js**

```
const useSelectComponent = CustomFabric({
    text: Input, // component view
    select: Select, // component view
});

function App() {
  const InputField = useSelectComponent('text');
  const SelectField = useSelectComponent('select');

  return (
      <form>
        <InputField/>
        <SelectField/>
      </form>
  );
}
```

In the interface, I indicate that the object element will contain a function, the second interface describes an object with entities. How to correctly specify the type for the HOC function so that I accept an object with a component

**hoc:**

```
interface PropsTypes {
  text: () => void;
  select: () => void;
}

interface Param {
  settings: PropsTypes;
}

export const CustomFabric: React.FC<Param> = ({ settings }: Param) => {
  const elements = Object.entries(settings);
  const newSettings = elements.reduce((acc: any, item: any) => {
    const key = item[0];
    const Component = item[1];

    acc[key] = (props: any) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState('');
      const onChange = (event: { target: { value: any } }) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
      };
      return <Component value={value} onChange={onChange} {...props} />;
    };

    return acc;
  }, {});

  return (type: any) => {
    return newSettings[type];
  };
};
```

Comment: A function component is a function which takes a single argument -- a props object -- and returns some JSX element.  Your `CustomFabric` takes props but it returns a function.  So it is inherently incompatible with the `React.FC` type.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what this code is supposed to do because the typings don't match how you are using it.  It looks like `text` and `select` are supposed to be components, but your interface says that they are functions which take no arguments and return nothing.

Comment: I also fundamentally don't "get" what the point is of having a controlled input where the state is behind a black box where you can't access it.  `CustomFabric` doesn't seem to give you any access to the state.  But it is probably better typed as a hook than as a function component.  It is most definitely not a function component.

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/DmM01N <- this fixes a lot of your issues, but doesn't understand your passed-through props.

Comment: @LindaPaisteThanks for help, it's work for me, if you can add as answer to question i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with this code, but the particular error that you posted is due to declaring the type of `CustomFabric` as `React.FC<Param>` when it is not a function component.

A function component is a function which takes a single argument -- a props object -- and returns some JSX element. Your `CustomFabric` takes props but it returns a `function`. So it is inherently incompatible with the `React.FC` type.

I'm trying to figure out what this code is supposed to do because the typings that you have don't match how you are using it. It looks like `text` and `select` are supposed to be components, but your interface says that they are functions which take no arguments and return nothing.  If they are components then they should use the `React.ComponentType<Props>` type.

I also fundamentally don't "get" what the point is of having a controlled input where the state is behind a black box where you can't access it. `CustomFabric` doesn't seem to give you any access to the state.  So I don't see what goal is being accomplished here.

But we can do a better job of properly typing what you have here, which is a function that return a hook.  This code fixes most of your issues by declaring that:

- `text` and `select` are components which take props `value` and `onChange`
- `CustomFabric` will be called with an object containing components for text and select
- `CustomFabric` returns a function which takes a name and returns a component.  That name must be either `'text'` or `'select'` and the returned component does not require any props.

There is still a lot of room for improvement.  For example your code passes through additional props to the input and select, but these types don't allow for any props other than `value` and `onChange`.  Your `settings` only has two properties, so you would get better type inference by dealing with those keys directly rather than looping through `Object.entries`.

```
type InputComponent = React.ComponentType<{value: string, onChange: React.ChangeEventHandler}>;

interface PropsTypes {
  text: InputComponent;
  select: InputComponent;
}

export const CustomFabric = (settings: PropsTypes) => {
  const elements = Object.entries(settings) as [keyof PropsTypes, InputComponent][];
  const newSettings = elements.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const key = item[0];
    const Component = item[1];

    acc[key] = (props: any) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState('');
      const onChange = (event: { target: { value: any } }) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
      };
      return <Component value={value} onChange={onChange} {...props} />;
    };

    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<keyof PropsTypes, React.FC>);

  return (type: keyof PropsTypes): React.FC => {
    return newSettings[type];
  };
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/DmM01N)